# SQL Server Management Studio: get data between two date columns

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need help getting sales dollars for each customer in their first 6 months (182 days) after signing up

Example:

[image]

I need to get total Sales $ between Sign-up Date and 6 Months, for each customers. So for customer A, it would be between 8/3/2019 to 2/1/2020, and so on.

Sales data is structured as Customer, Date, Sales $

Example:

[image]

I would think I need to write some kind of loop? The customer list is over 100,000 rows.

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with a single query, using a combination of JOINs, GROUP BY and aggregation.  Given that the idea of StackOverflow is to not necessarily have your work done for you, but rather to give it a crack yourself and then ask for assistance with specific issues, if you come back and update your question with your query attempts, and where things might not be going as you expect, then others will be able to assist

Comment: I'm able to get sales $ for each customer, in same date range. I can post this query but it seems pointless because it is not what I need. For this purpose, I need sales for each customer in different date range, because each customer signed up at different time. I'm don't know where to start with this.

Comment: I posted a really rough example as an answer, so that should help get you started.  You didn't post specific table structures in your question, so I've just generically named things so that you'll hopefully understand how to translate to your own data

Comment: @Blue Can you post your sample table and few insert statements so that we can help you?

Answer (score 1):

An example that you can follow:

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerName,
    c.SignUpDate,
    DATEADD(day, 182, c.SignUpDate) AS [6MonthDate],
    ISNULL(SUM(s.SaleAmount), 0) AS [6MonthSalesTotal]
FROM
    Customer c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales s
    ON s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    AND s.DateOfSale BETWEEN c.SignUpDate AND DATEADD(day, 182, c.SignUpDate)
GROUP BY c.CustomerName, c.SignUpDate, DATEADD(day, 182, c.SignUpDate);
```

Comment: just because we are sharing "tips", it's not needed to include in the `group by` deterministic functions over a field that already has been included in the `group by`. You can do it (and it works), but its unnecesary

Comment: @JaimeDrq - this is true.  Just my force of habit, I guess

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the database engine you are using, but for example, with sql server, the query should look like this

```
select 
  c.customer,
  c."sign-up Date",
  dateadd(month,6,c."sign-up Date") as SixMonths,
  sum(d.sales) as sales
from customers c
  join sales s
      on c.customer = s.customer
     and s.Date between c."sign-up Date" and dateadd(month,6,c."sign-up Date")
group by c.customer, c."sign-up Date"
```

It's not recommended using this kind of column names `"sign-up Date"`. In addition, column names matching with reserved words (sales.date) is also a bad practice.

Comment: True that OP didn't tag the RDBMS, but did note "SQL SSMS" (SQL Server Management Studio) in the question title.  Also, SQL Server's DATEADD() function takes parameters in the order (datepart, number, date).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can test this query. I added sample table and data I used. You can easily convert this to your tables and columns. I used simple group by with an Inner join to tables to filter out relevant records. Let me know if this helps, or need and alterations.

Answer:

```
 SELECT 
   [A].[Customer]
   ,[A].[Signupdate]
   ,[A].[Six_months]
   ,SUM([B].[Sales]) as [Total_Sales] 
FROM  table_1 AS [A]
   INNER JOIN table_2  AS [B]
      ON [A].[Customer] = [B].[Cusomer]
WHERE [B].[date] BETWEEN  [A].[Signupdate] AND [A].[Six_months]
GROUP BY  [A].[Customer]
   ,[A].[Signupdate]
   ,[A].[Six_months]
```

below are my tables and insert scripts I used to get the output:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_1](
  [Customer] [varchar](3) NULL,
  [Signupdate] [date] NULL,
  [Six_months] [date] NULL,
  [sales] [decimal](10, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_2](
  [Cusomer] [varchar](3) NULL,
  [date] [date] NULL,
   [Sales] [decimal](10, 2) NULL
) 


INSERT [dbo].[table_1] ([Customer], [Signupdate], [Six_months], [sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-02-01' AS Date), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_1] ([Customer], [Signupdate], [Six_months], [sales]) VALUES (N'B', CAST(N'2020-02-10' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-08-10' AS Date), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_1] ([Customer], [Signupdate], [Six_months], [sales]) VALUES (N'C', CAST(N'2020-08-19' AS Date), CAST(N'2021-02-17' AS Date), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2019-02-10' AS Date), CAST(10.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2019-02-22' AS Date), CAST(20.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2019-02-15' AS Date), CAST(5.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'B', CAST(N'2020-02-10' AS Date), CAST(10.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2020-02-22' AS Date), CAST(20.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2020-03-15' AS Date), CAST(5.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'B', CAST(N'2021-02-12' AS Date), CAST(20.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'B', CAST(N'2020-02-14' AS Date), CAST(5.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'B', CAST(N'2020-02-12' AS Date), CAST(20.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'B', CAST(N'2020-02-14' AS Date), CAST(5.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2020-02-10' AS Date), CAST(10.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2020-02-22' AS Date), CAST(20.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2019-03-15' AS Date), CAST(5.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2019-09-10' AS Date), CAST(10.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2019-10-22' AS Date), CAST(20.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[table_2] ([Cusomer], [date], [Sales]) VALUES (N'A', CAST(N'2019-10-15' AS Date), CAST(5.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @Blue Can you have a look??

Comment: where's the query?

Comment: @JaimeDrq Here I edited the answer so that you can find the query on top and sample data below the query. Sorry for the inconvenience of finding the query. :)

Comment: Your answer is invalid, the six_months field doesn't exist in the OP data, and it's not needed to create it to solve this question. Sorry but I have to downvote.

Comment: @JaimeDrq the owner of the question should confirm. Not you.  I gave a try with the information he provided. If he says some change I will do that for him..

Comment: believe me... it's not needed to do all what you suggest to resolve que question.

Answer (score -2):

You should apply a JOIN based on the column CUSTOMERS, then make a SUM aggregation with a GROUP BY based on CUSTOMERS, must set the necessary condition in the WHERE sentence so you can narrow the data between the selected dates.

Comment: In fact, applying date filters in the WHERE clause will not be the correct approach for the OP to achieve the desired outcome.  Applying date filters in there WHERE clause will likely just end up excluding some customer rows.  The query needs to sum the total of sales based on each customer's different sign-up date (and a 6-month date range after the sign-up date).